# Cannot call method from extended ViewGroup

Tags: java, android

I have extended a `LinearLayout` which represents my main ui block and inside this I use two more extended `LinearLayout` .

If i have to write it down with pseudo code is like this :

```
Bar extends LinearLayout 
init() //here I initialize the LinearLayout and set some properties.
//the Constructor
    public Bar(Context context, int height ) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.height = height;
    init();    //calling init() inside the constructor
}
```

and inside Bar the code is :

```
    public void create() {
    upLinearLayout = new UpLinearLayout(context, 40 );
    downLinearLayout = new DownLinearLayout(context, 160);

    this.addView(upLinearLayout);
    this.addView(downLinearLayout);
}
```

So when I'm on my MainActivity I give :

```
    Bar bb = new mBar(this, 300);
    bar.create();
```

where `create()` is :

```
public void create() {
    upLinearLayout = new UpLinearLayout(context, 40 );
    downLinearLayout = new DownLinearLayout(context, 160);

    this.addView(upLinearLayout);
    this.addView(downLinearLayout);
}
```

So far the code is working great. 
But I cannot call from Bar methods that belong to upLinearLayout or downLinearLayout e.g. :

```
    public void anotherButton(Context context) {
    Button button1 = new Button(context);
    button1.setText("Testing");
    button1.setTextSize(18);
    this.addView(button1);
}
```

Now inside the Bar class I can't do:

```
        UpLinearLayout up = new UpLinearLayout(context, 65);
    up.anotherButton(context);
```

it gives me error :

```
Error:(47, 11) error: cannot find symbol method anotherButton(Context)
```

tl;dr In MainActivity I can call all public methods of `Bar` - but I can't do the same inside extended `Bar` for  other extended classes. 
What I can do is only initialize them.

[image: create()]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now inside the Bar class I can't do:

```
UpLinearLayout up = new UpLinearLayout(context, 65);
up.anotherButton(context);
```

you can't because `anotherButton` is a method of `Bar`, but you are calling on an instance of `UpLinearLayout` which has not a method call `anotherButton`. If you want to add a `Button` to `UpLinearLayout` from bar you could do:

```
public void anotherButton(LinearLayout layout) {
    Button button1 = new Button(getContext());
    button1.setText("Testing");
    button1.setTextSize(18);
    layout.addView(button1);
}
```

and then call it like `anotherButton(up);`

or add `anotherButton` in `UpLinearLayout`. And don't forget to cast to the exact type if you declared your member with the Base class. E.g.

You declared

```
LinearLayout upperLayout;
```

if you want to access a method of your custom

```
UpperLinearLayout extend LinearLayout
```

you have to cast `upperLayout` explicitly to `UpperLinearLayout`

Comment: No, anotherButton() belongs to the UpLinearLayout class.

Comment: anotherBar or anotherButton ? If you had the method, the compiler wouldn't have complained

Comment: It's anotherButton sorry my mistake here. Same code is for DownLinearLayout but with a different method.

Comment: can you post UpLinearLayout? another pastebin

Comment: And in the Bar class I have :    public void create() {
        upLinearLayout = new UpLinearLayout(context, 40 );
        downLinearLayout = new DownLinearLayout(context, 160);

        this.addView(upLinearLayout);
        this.addView(downLinearLayout);
    }

Comment: you are welcome. UpperLayout has no anotherButton method. Also UpLinearLayout and DownLinearLayout look the same to me. You should avoid duplicating code. It makes the maintainability a nightmare

Comment: Can you check the image I just uploaded in my question? What happens to downLinearLayout for anotherButton is the same to upLinearLayout for `create`. 
Thanks for the comments - I'll try to create a BaseLinearLayout and  extend from there

Comment: you are trying to call a method of `UpLinearLayout` that doesn't exits. You have create which does the same thing

Comment: did you declared `LinearLayout upLinearLayout` or `UpLinearLayout upLinearLayout`?

Comment: that's why you don't find your custom methods. try with `((UpLinearLayout) upLinearLayout).create(getContext());`